# Alias column in new Drupal7 database API

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, dbo

I'm working through my queries, changing them over to the new API.

I'm trying to SELECT an alias that includes as CASE statement. Here is my original SQL:

```
SUM(CASE MONTH(data.start) WHEN 1 THEN data.accepted END) AS 'Jan',
```

And this is what I'm trying with the new API:

```
->addField('data',  SUM(CASE MONTH('start') WHEN 1 THEN data.accepted END), 'Jan');
```

However even before I run the query Eclipse is suggesting there is a syntax error here.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`SelectQuery::addExpression()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddExpression/7)

```
$expr = "SUM(CASE MONTH('start') WHEN 1 THEN data.accepted END)";
$query->addExpression($expr, 'Jan');
```